# More than one Case in same query are generating more than one row

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-administration, sapb1

My problem is actually I have multiple tables and I'm using two `case` statements to generate one column for `ARV1` and one for `ICA1`, but I need the results are generated in the same row.  When I use`case`, generate the two columns but the values are displayed in two rows.  What am I missing?

the thing is, i have an invoice the table OINV and have the table INV5 that is the table with the Holding Taxes, i need to put on the same row the invoice with all the Holding Taxes in different columns that are applying on it, thanks

this is the example tables

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
  Id INT, InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(10), Total INT    
)

INSERT INTO Invoice
VALUES
(1,'200000',100),
(2,'200001',200),
(3,'200002',500),
(4,'200003',700),
(5,'200004',200),
(6,'200005',100),
(7,'200006',300)

CREATE TABLE HoldingTaxes
(
 Id INT, HoldingTaxCode VARCHAR(10),HoldedAmount INT) 
)

INSERT INTO HoldingTaxes
VALUES
(1,'ARV1',20),
(1,'ARV2',30),
(1,'ARV3',35),
(2,'ICA1',20),
(2,'ARV1',10),
(1,'ICA3',50)
```

I want a query that returns something like this:

```
InvoiceNumber Total  ARV1 ARV2 ARV3  ICA1  ICA2   ICA3
200000          100   20   30   35   null   null   50
```

This is what i am trying to do with my real tables

```
SELECT T0.DocNum [No. Factura],
CASE
WHEN t5.WTCode ='ARV1' and (t5.U_Ret_ML <>0 AND t5.U_Ret_ML is not null)
THEN 'Perro1'
else NULL
end AS ARV1
,
CASE
WHEN t5.WTCode ='ICA1' and (t5.U_Ret_ML <>0 AND t5.U_Ret_ML is not null)
THEN 'Perro2'
else NULL
end AS ICA1
FROM OINV T0
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T2.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode
INNER JOIN INV5 T5 ON T5.AbsEntry = T0.DocEntry
WHERE T1.WhsCode = T3.WhsCode`enter code here`
GROUP BY T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T0.DocTotal, T0.GrosProfit, T4.SlpName,T5.WTCODE,t5.U_Ret_ML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PIVOT to solve this - as demonstrated in the SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT  EmpName
       ,CASE WHEN ARV1 > 0 THEN 'PERRO1' ELSE NULL END
       ,CASE WHEN ARV2 > 0 THEN 'PERRO2' ELSE NULL END
       ,CASE WHEN ICA1 > 0 THEN 'PERRO3' ELSE NULL END
FROM (SELECT t0.EmpName, t1.Name, t1.Value 
      FROM Table0 t0 INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t0.Id = t1.Id ) as  src 
PIVOT (
  MAX(src.Value) 
  FOR src.Name IN ([ARV1],[ARV2],[ICA1])) as p
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6ff0/2

If your having issues and willing to share your structure, I can put this into a a closer match to what you are using on SQL Fiddle.

Edit:

Based on the update you gave, here is the fiddle I created with the pivot.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47511/4

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT    InvoiceNumber  = Invoice.InvoiceNumber
         ,Total          = Invoice.Total
         ,HoldingTaxCode = HoldingTaxes.HoldingTaxCode
         ,HoldedAmount   = HoldingTaxes.HoldedAmount
FROM      Invoice  
LEFT JOIN HoldingTaxes 
ON        Invoice.Id = HoldingTaxes.Id) PivotSource
PIVOT
(
 SUM(HoldedAmount) FOR HoldingTaxCode IN(ARV1, ARV2, ARV3, ICA1, ICA2, ICA3)  
) PivotData
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way :

> SELECT inv.InvoiceNumber,inv.Total,[ARV1],[ARV2],[ARV3],[ICA1],[ICA2],[ICA3]
>   FROM INVOICE inv
>   JOIN(
>   SELECT id,[ARV1],[ARV2],[ARV3],[ICA1],[ICA2],[ICA3]
>   FROM 
>   (SELECT * FROM HoldingTaxes ) t1
>   PIVOT(SUM(HoldedAmount) for HoldingTaxCode in 
>   ([ARV1],[ARV2],[ARV3],[ICA1],[ICA2],[ICA3])) t2
>   ) ht 
>   ON inv.id =ht.id

sql fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea3a4/10

Answer (score 0):

The two `CASE` expressions employ the same logic.  Only the value in `t5.WTCode` is different.  Since that column is unlikely to have the value `ARV1` and `ICA1` at the same time you'll always get a `NULL` in at least one of the computed columns in any row.

Comment: so what should i do to get the on same row ARV1 And ICA1 the table INV5 T5 has the two values?, thanks

Comment: @Skatalitico - You can't.  Since you also `GROUP BY` `t5.WTCode` and you are expecting it to have (at least) two different values then you will get multiple rows.  Perhaps you aren't summarizing the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting different case statements for 2 different values. Therefore for each row one of them would be valid and other one null, which is what you are getting.

Comment: the thing is, i have an invoice the table OINV and have the table INV5 that is the table with the retentions, i need to put on the same row the invoice with all the retentions in different columns that are applying on it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved my issue, thanks to everyone for the help

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(t5.WTCode) 
            FROM INV5 T5
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Factura, Fecha, SN, TotalFacturaSinImpuesto, Total$Descuento, Total$Impuesto, Total$Retenciones, Total$Factura, CostoTotal$Factura, Margen$Factura, Costo$PromedioInventario, Margen$Inventario, NombreVendedor, ' + @cols + ' from
            (
                select T0.DocNum [Factura], T0.DocDate [Fecha], T0.CardName [SN],SUM(T1.LineTotal) [TotalFacturaSinImpuesto], T0.DiscSum [Total$Descuento],  T0.VatSum [Total$Impuesto],(T0.WTSum*-1) [Total$Retenciones],t5.WTCode [CodigoRetencion],t5.U_Ret_ML [CantidadRetenida],T0.DocTotal [Total$Factura],SUM(T1.GrossBuyPr*T1.Quantity) [CostoTotal$Factura], T0.GrosProfit [Margen$Factura],SUM(T1.Quantity*T3.AvgPrice) [Costo$PromedioInventario],(SUM(T1.LineTotal*T1.Quantity))-(SUM(T1.Quantity*T3.AvgPrice)) [Margen$Inventario], T4.SlpName [NombreVendedor]
                FROM OINV T0
                INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
                INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode 
                INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
                INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T2.ItemCode = T3.ItemCode
                INNER JOIN INV5 T5 ON T5.AbsEntry = T0.DocEntry
                WHERE T1.WhsCode = T3.WhsCode 
                GROUP BY T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate, T0.CardName,T0.BaseAmnt, T0.DiscSum,  T0.VatSum,  T0.WTSum,T0.DocTotal, T0.GrosProfit, T4.SlpName,T5.WTCODE,T5.U_RET_ML
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(CantidadRetenida)
                for CodigoRetencion in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```